# QT 4.7.4 QNetwork on symbian using 3g

Tags: qt, symbian, qnetworkaccessmanager, qt-mobility, qt-quick

is it possible to use QNetworkRequest on symbian to make a HTTP request via 3G ?
I've a code that work on simulator, but when i put it in device, the device try to connect via wifi.

i've try to add this on my pro file :

```
QT += network

symbian {
TARGET.CAPABILITY = NetworkServices
}

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = bearer
```

But it's still not working...i'm using 4.7.4.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't it up the user to specify where does he want the request to be done? I mean there are user's who did not purchase a data package, so they only want to use wifi networks. I know this is nothing to do with a costum application, but isn't the problem laying in the phone settings?

Comment: i saw other app downloaded on ovi store that ask for this permission to user. If it's possible, i would like to check if a Wifi network is ready to use, if not try to use 3G network if user is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My operator SFR (french) allow the connexion from some User-Agent !

You can change the user agent like this :

```
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setRawHeader("User-Agent", “Mozilla/5.0 (Nokia; Qt; Symbian)");
```